# Use piece of an anctivity in an other activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I have 3 Activities in my application and I want to use a piece of those Activities in another Activity. But Fragments and Intents give the whole content of an Activity.
Is there any way to use just some component of an Activity in another Activity and use the first Activity's code in a second Activity, that I want to use a piece of the first Activity?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a separate java class. Create a function. Create object in your activity. Call that function. Same in other activities.

Comment: Thanks , i think this is the best way 

Answer (score 0):

Each Activity is totally separate when you change activities the first one is paused, so the answer is no you cannot use part of one activity in another.